# Border radius is not working in Chrome & Safari Browser

Tags: html, css

I'm using border radius for my images, the corner of the images are not getting rounded.

But the same code was working properly in Mozila Firefox.

CSS :

```
 body img { 
     border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border: 3px solid #ed1d24;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Not reproducible in Chrome 24beta. Please provide more information. Check whether the problem occurs if you test the style sheet on a page that has nothing but an `img` element (no other style sheet).

Comment: border-radius has been standardized, you don't need the vendor prefixes anymore.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome Version 23.0.1271.95 m : http://jsfiddle.net/82B6c/

Comment: My Chrome Version is 23.0.1271.95 m, But it's not working.

Comment: @RK, does this happen in the minimized test I suggested? For all images? What happens when you increase border width?

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela Yes it happens for all images. if I increased the border size it remains the sam. the images not getting rounded.

Comment: @RK, in the image (screenshot?) added to the question, the corners are rounds. The border is just very thin and dim there. Is this what you mean? What is the exact code you used for that? It seems to have a border thicker than 1px. Did you magnify the screen shot?

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela yes the corners are getting dim. in the screenshot i use border 3px. and not getting full border at the corners.

Comment: @RK, then it remains a mystery, unless there is some other stylesheet affecting the situation (but I presume that you checked the situation using a *minimal* document as I suggested). You could still post a URL of a demo just to make sure there’s not something we’ve overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

set the border first, and then override its radius:

```
 body img { 
    border: 1px solid #ed1d24;
     border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    }
```

[edit]

Actually I can only conclude that it works one way or the other. I'm using Chrome myself and both images in this fiddle have rounded corners.

http://jsfiddle.net/aqBA7/

Comment: Why would this affect the situation? The order of declarations within a rule is immaterial by the specs. It would be an odd bug if it were not.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks, But still I having problem with the corners. It remains the same no changes happen.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I figured that border-radius was a sub property of border, just as setting a border overwrites border-left. Of course this isn't the case, so I edited my answer about 5 minutes before your comment.

Comment: @RK. Can you then please post the full code or a link to the website? As I and a couple of others have confirmed: the style in itself works fine, so you may have another error.

Comment: @GolezTrol Please loko this http://jsfiddle.net/Rajaovi/D7MHh/  I'm getting correctly in fiddle but not in browser.

Comment: @RK. So the fiddle is useless, and it proves my point that it is a different issue in your page.

Comment: @GolezTrol please look at the image what I gonna do now.

Answer (score 1):

There must be an error somewhere else in your code, `border-radius` works perfectly fine in Google Chrome as GolezTrol has already shown, your CSS is also correct.

Try opening the developer tools and check, if the styles are properly applied to your `img` element.

Comment: Yes i checked the styles are applied to img

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper `div` and apply `border` and `border-radius` to the `#wrapper` and only `border-radius` to the image inside.  I reduced the `border-radius` on the image by the same exact amount as the `border` `width` of the `wrapper` in order to properly fill out the container with the image.  If you make the `border-radius` the same on both elements, you'll see a slight gap in the corners because the of the minor difference in sizes caused by the `border` `width`.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01452/fer1_1452403i.jpg" width="620" height="388" alt="" /> 
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 620px; height: 388px;
    border: 2px solid #ed1d24;
    border-radius: 20px;
}    

#wrapper img { 
    border-radius: 18px; /* wrapper radius minus wrapper border width */
}​
```

[**DEMO tested in Safari**:](http://jsfiddle.net/D7MHh/2/)

http://jsfiddle.net/D7MHh/2/

**Screenshot of jsFiddle in Safari**:

[image: Screenshot in Safari of jsFiddle]